# Error with 'make_standalone_toolchain.py'

Tags: android, python, command-line, cmd, toolchain

I ran this line in cmd:

```
<NDK root dir>/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py --arch arm --api 21 --stl=libc++ --install-dir /tmp/my-android-toolchain
```

It returns:

```
usage: make_standalone_toolchain.py [-h] --arch
                                    {arm,arm64,mips,mips64,x86,x86_64}
                                    [--api API]
                                    [--stl {gnustl,libc++,stlport}] [--force]
                                    [-v]
                                    [--package-dir PACKAGE_DIR | --install-dir INSTALL_DIR]
make_standalone_toolchain.py: error: argument --arch is required
```

Why won't it run?

EDIT: the purpose of the file is to create a toolchain.

***EDIT:*** isn't arch already stated? Is there the probability of something being wrong with my pc?

Answer (score 0):

Did you cut-and-paste that command line from Google's web page?

If so, edit the line by removing all the characters that *look like* `-` and typing real `-` in their places. Text that's been processed through multiple programs sometimes ends up with characters that look like `-`, but have different character codes.